# Laravel 5 Models and scoping with custom methods

Tags: php, mysql, methods, laravel-5, models

I have a Model that I created a custom method for to retrieve data from two tables (the model and a table that is related) to avoid multiple querying. Can't say I'm an expert in Laravel, but I do ok.
Here is the method: (class is Criteria)

```
public static function withDiagnostic()
{
    return (\DB::select(\DB::raw("SELECT productspecs.product_id AS productId, criteria.id as criteriaId,criteria.name as criteriaName,diagnostic.name as diagnosticName ".
                  "FROM criteria, diagnostic,productspecs ".
                  "WHERE productspecs.criteria_id=criteria.id ".
                  "AND productspecs.diagnostic_id=diagnostic.id ".
                  "AND criteria.diagnostic_id = diagnostic.id ".
                  "AND criteria.inactive=0 ".
                  "ORDER by diagnostic.name,criteria.name")));
}
```

I'd like to be able to `Criteria::withDiagnostic()->where('productId',20)` but I get a method where not defined.

What do I need to do (without creating a second method to do this?)

and can that custom query be re-written in Eloquent only? My Eloquent is not so good for multiple table joins and unions etc.

Comment: Scopes are for Eloquent queries, not `DB::raw` calls.

Comment: sorry. you are right. originally this wasn't a static function, I was using it as a scope and it was called scopemenuitems, which is why I referred to scoping in the title. my bad. Given what it is now, however, any thoughts?

Comment: ceejayoz - are you saying that if this query was re-written in Eloquent Query Builder I could do  Criteria::withDiagnostic()->where('productId',20)?